# Circuit help. I want a Voltage gain from 5 volts to 10 volts.

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, integrated-circuit

I need some circuit help.. I am trying to boost my voltage from a 5v source to a 10v output so I want a Gain of 2. I Ran the simulation and built the circuit exactly how it is shown in the figure below. I am using an op-amp 471CN and when I test the circuits output (Vout) I still only get a 5 volt output. I'm fairly new at this so can anyone help me with trying to figure out why i'm not getting 10 volt output. I'm sure it's simple but I just don't see it now. Thank you for your time.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fULXzf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: A better alternative to still run it on 5V would be a voltage doubler or Boost.

Comment: You haven't shown in your circuit what you used to power your opamp. It can't produce more than you supply it with (much less in the case of a 741).

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Is the 5 volts a signal of some sort that you want to feed to an input that expects 10 volts, or do you need the 10 volts as a power supply for your circuit?  Note that most op-amps can only deliver low currents, and, as others say, cannot produce an output voltage that exceeds their own power supply voltage.

Answer (score 6):

You will need to *supply* the op amp with a voltage high enough to contain both the output and any headroom the op amp needs to operate in, so that would mean a supply of at least 11.5V or so.

If you do not have a supply high enough then you will need to use a boost regulator, charge pump, or voltage multiplier to increase the voltage instead.